# Charts generated by code have inconsistent axis and label sizes

Tags: .net, charts, data-visualization, mschart, docx

I'm generating `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting` Charts to dynamically insert them into a `.docx` document.
The problem is that their width depends on the size of both the graph *and* the length of the axis labels, so the graphs with longer labels end up appearing smaller on the output document.

I use a method that splices the labels onto different lines but this doesn't seem to affect the size of the graph.

Here is one of my chart-generating methods:

```
private static MemoryStream CreateRadarChartImage(IEnumerable<SectionDs> sections)
    {
        var chart = new Chart { BackColor = Color.Transparent, Width = 550, Height = 350 };

        var series = new Series("Series")
                         {
                             ChartArea = "chartArea",
                             ChartType = SeriesChartType.Radar,
                             BorderWidth = 1,
                             BorderColor = Color.Black,
                             BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid,
                             Color = Color.Transparent
                         };
        foreach (SectionDs section in sections)
        {
            var labelText = SpliceText(section.Name, 14);

            series.Points.Add(
                new DataPoint { AxisLabel = labelText, LabelAngle = 40, YValues = new[] { section.OverallScore * 100 } });
        }

        chart.Series.Add(series);

        var chartArea = new ChartArea("chartArea") { BackColor = Color.Transparent, AxisY = { Maximum = 100 }, AxisX = { LabelStyle = { Font = new Font("Calibri", 15f) } } };
        chart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);

        var chartImage = new MemoryStream();
        chart.SaveImage(chartImage, ChartImageFormat.Png);
        return chartImage;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var chartArea = new ChartArea("chartArea") { BackColor = Color.Transparent, AxisY = { Maximum = 100 }, AxisX = { LabelStyle = { Font = new Font("Calibri", 15f) } } };
chartArea.AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = false;
chart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);
```

This will stop the automatic fitting of labels so each chart will have the same size labels. You may need to do some manual formatting to the labels now though

Comment: My charts all had the same label sizes already - it's their lengths that vary. Thanks for the answer though.